# Concatenate multiple rows into single column where data coming from multiple tables

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have data coming from different tables where there are multiple rows of data in a column which I want to concatenate into one column.  something like this

```
Select A.column1,
B.column1, 
A.column3,
C.column1,
C.column4,
D.column1
FROM TableA A, TableB B, TableC C, TableD D
WHERE 
A.Id=B.ID
AND B.ID=C.ID
AND A.code=D.code
```

the output i get is like this

```
1   Name A  Table C Data    Table D data
1   Name B  Table C Data    Table D data
1   Name C  Table C Data    Table D data
2   Name D  Table C Data    Table D data
2   Name A  Table C Data    Table D data
2   Name R  Table C Data    Table D data
3   Name F  Table C Data    Table D data
4   Name F  Table C Data    Table D data
4   Name E  Table C Data    Table D data
4   Name D  Table C Data    Table D data
4   Name C  Table C Data    Table D data
```

Except column B everything else is repeating since the column B is having different data. I want to concatenate all the names into one column so that I don't get other columns to be repetitive. I tried using LISTAGG function but it says not a single-group by function for the first row. please guide me 
how to acheive this. I want the output to be like

```
1   Name A,Name B Name C         Table C Data   Table D data
2   Name D,Name A, Name R        Table C Data   Table D data
3   Name F                       Table C Data   Table D data
4   Name F,Name E,Name D,Name C  Table C Data   Table D data
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work I think

```
select A.column1,listagg(B.column1,',') within group (order by B.column1),
A.column3,
C.column1,
C.column4,
D.column1
FROM TableA A, TableB B, TableC C, TableD D
WHERE 
A.Id=B.ID
AND B.ID=C.ID
AND A.code=D.code
group by A.column1,
A.column3,
C.column1,
C.column4,
D.column1;
```

Comment: Thanks @arunb2w. It worked. I had tried this but had missed out the last group by function.

Answer (score 0):

Should be a simple use of `LISTAGG`.

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS(
  2  SELECT 1 col1,  'Name A' col2,  'TABLE C Data' col3,    'TABLE D Data' col4 from dual union all
  3  SELECT 1,   'Name B',   'TABLE C Data',    'TABLE D Data' from dual union all
  4  SELECT 1 ,  'Name C',   'TABLE C Data',    'TABLE D Data' from dual union all
  5  SELECT 2  , 'Name D',   'TABLE C Data',    'TABLE D Data' FROM dual UNION ALL
  6  SELECT 2   ,'Name A',   'TABLE C Data',    'TABLE D Data' FROM dual UNION ALL
  7  SELECT 2 ,  'Name R',  'TABLE C Data',    'TABLE D Data' from dual union all
  8  SELECT 3 ,  'Name F',  'TABLE C Data',    'TABLE D Data' FROM dual UNION ALL
  9  SELECT 4 ,  'Name F',  'TABLE C Data',    'TABLE D Data' FROM dual UNION ALL
 10  SELECT 4 ,  'Name E',  'TABLE C Data',    'TABLE D Data' from dual union all
 11  SELECT 4 ,  'Name D',   'TABLE C Data',    'TABLE D Data' FROM dual UNION ALL
 12  SELECT 4 ,  'Name C',   'TABLE C Data',    'TABLE D Data' from dual
 13  )
 14  SELECT COL1,
 15    listagg(COL2,',') WITHIN GROUP (
 16  ORDER BY COL2) COL2,
 17    COL3,
 18    COL4
 19  FROM DATA
 20  GROUP BY COL1,
 21    COL3,
 22    COL4
 23  /

      COL1 COL2                           COL3            COL4
---------- ------------------------------ --------------- --------------------
         1 Name A,Name B,Name C           TABLE C Data    TABLE D Data
         2 Name A,Name D,Name R           TABLE C Data    TABLE D Data
         3 Name F                         TABLE C Data    TABLE D Data
         4 Name C,Name D,Name E,Name F    TABLE C Data    TABLE D Data

SQL>
```